# What is the electron effective mass value for a $\rm InSb$ lattice?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, crystals, electronic-band-theory, nanoscience

I'm trying to calculate the Thomas-Fermi screening length of the III-V semiconductor $\rm InSb$ with doping level $n = 5 \times 10^{18} \text{cm}^{-3}$ ($5 \times 10^{24} \text{m}^{-3} $ in SI units) and with an electron density of the same value indicating that all donors are ionised.

I know I must use the equation:

$$\lambda_{TF}^2 = \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^{1/3} \frac{a_0^*}{4n^{1/3}} \tag{1}$$

where $\lambda_{TF}$ indicates the screening-length, and $a^*_0$, shown below, depends on the Bohr radius ($ 5.29 \times 10^{−11} \text{m}$), on the electron effective mass (I think, I am not entirely sure) , $m^*$, and on the static dielectric constant of the $\rm InSb$, $\epsilon(0)$.

$$a^*_0 = \frac{\epsilon(0) a_0}{m^*} \tag{2}$$

**How do I know the correct effective mass value, $m^*$, to use on eq. $(2)$?**

On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(solid-state_physics)) on "Effective mass (Solid-State Physics)" a table shows the values for the "Density of states effective mass in various semiconductors" for $\rm InSb$: for electrons the value is $0.013$ and for holes it is $0.6$.

**How do I know which of these two values to choose (electrons or holes)? Is it related to the fact that all donors are ionised, as stated in the first sentence?**

Comment: But why? Why are you asking for a mathematical confirmation of a measured value? It is the other way around: it is the mathematical calculations that need experimental confirmation before we can trust them.

Comment: I have just found various values $\epsilon(0)$ and I was wondering if anyone knew of a more up to date value. But that isn't the main point of my question, I was meant to delete that bit, thank you for noticing.

Any information regarding the other values/questions, would you be deeply appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is an $n$-doped material, so there are almost no holes. They do not play a part in screening, their effective mass is irrelevant here.

Comment: So that would indicate that the value for the effective mass would be $m^* = 0.13$ would that be so? Meaning, that the value would be $m^*=0.13m_e$ where $m_e$ represents the rest mass of an electron. Is this so?

Comment: I do not know these values by heart, and I am not going to do your homework for you. But in your question you wrote that it was $0.013\ m_e$. So I would suggest you check a reliable source.

Comment: It is not homework, but thank you anyway. For whoever might be interested in knowing, the value presented on the Wikipedia page corresponds to 0.13 times the rest mass of the electron.  Indicating a value for $m^*= 0.13 m_e= 1.1843 \times 10^{-31}$.